# java "database is locked" SQL exception

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm creating a really DB intensive java program, but I encountered an error on the connections. The code is:

```
try{
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        conn = DBConnection.dbconnection();
        st = conn.createStatement();
        String s = "select *  from tab2DB order by Scadenza";
        rs = st.executeQuery(s);
        while(rs.next()){
            ResultSet rs2;
            PreparedStatement st2;
            conn2 = DBConnection.connection();
            String s2 = "select * from Prodotti where Nome = ?";
            st2 = conn2.prepareStatement(s2);
            st2.setString(1, rs.getString("Prodotto"));
            rs2 = st2.executeQuery();               
            while(rs2.next()){
                
                Date localDate = new Date();
                
                String scadenza =  rs.getString("Scadenza");
                DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ITALIAN);
                Date date = format.parse(scadenza);
                
                
                
                if(localDate.after(date)){
                        conn3 = DBConnection.dbconnection();        
                        String query ="insert into tabDB values ('"+nomeord+"','"+prodottoord+"','"+quantitàord+"')";
                        Statement stmt;
                        stmt = conn3.createStatement();
                        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                        conn3.close();
                        continue;
                }
                
                //other building of interface in the while, omitted for clarity purpose
                conn2.close();
                rs2.close();
                }
                conn.close();
                rs.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the error is on the if(localDate.after(date)){...}
where  stmt.executeUpdate(query); triggers an error and crashes the program. I think the problem here is that the DB has already a connection open and can't handle conn3, but I need those other connections for  the while cycle and in the same time I need to be able to give the orders inside the if while in the cycle. How can I make it so that the new order does not interfere with the while cycles but in the same time executes the query?

*(What the query tries to do may not work in the code above, this is a snippet of a way larger class.)*

Comment: Show full stack trace please

Comment: Why did you put `mysql` and `sql-server` tags? What exact DB are you using?

Comment: This is because you are never closing your connections. Use a better data Structure for this. Save your resultSets in Maps or Arrays. Or Usea better Query For this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could utilize try-with-resources, which ensures that all resources are closed at the end of the statement.

Example:

```
try (Connection con = ConnectionManager.dbconnection();
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)) {
        while(resultSet.next) {
            //Add desired values to data structure
        }
}
```

Additionally, as other users have mentioned, I recommend iterating through the results and adding to something like a List, Set, or Map. This way you can close the connection and still access the data from another object.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `close()` on your `Connection` objects as soon as your query has been executed.

Also, 
`conn1` gets instantiated to `DBConnection.dbconnection();`
`conn2` gets instantiated to `DBConnection.connection();`
`conn3` gets instantiated to `DBConnection.dbconnection();`

See the difference?

Comment: The different calls are due to me translating the code from Italian class names to English to make it more readable for the site. Something slipped through and it ended calling different things in here, on the code it is correct.  Sadly closing the connection makes it impossible to do the while cycle correctly, so I am forced to keep it open... I found a workaround saving information inside some arrays in the if() and then calling a new connection in the end of the document, after all the connections are close. Thank you very much for the help though!